# Can't change top property with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, button, slide

I've got a little button and a piece of javascript code as well as css.I want my button search to change top position from -1px to 51px, but javascript doesn't seem to respond to me changing this property.So could anybody tell me where is my mistake.I suppose that it may have something to with css's position property.Anyway,would be grateful for any help.And one more question:can i make my box kind a like slide down smoothly and not just pop up?But i'm only interested in javascript now,not jquery
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#searchButton{
position:fixed;
border:1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
border-right:none;
border-top:none;
width:60px;
height:20px;
top:-1px;
right:-2px;
border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
background:rgb(30,114,41);
}
#searchButton :hover{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#searchButton a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
text-align:center;
color:white;
padding:0;
margin:0;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.searchBox p{
position:absolute;
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
border-radius:2px;
box-shadow:0 1px 2px 2px #1F0000;
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 2px #1F0000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 2px #1F0000;
border-top:none;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
width:200px;
height:50px;
top:0;
right:0;
margin:0;
display:none;
font-size:15px;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
color:white;
}

</style>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function popUp(menu){
    var searchBox = document.getElementById(menu).style;
    var searcButton = document.getElementById('searchButton').style;
    if(searchBox.display == "none"){
        searchBox.display = "block";
        searchButton.top = 0 + "px";
        }
    else{
        searchBox.display = "none";
        searchButton.top = 51 + "px";
        }

};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class = "searchBox">
    <p id = "paragraph"><input type = "text" name = "serachBar"/>
    <input type = "button" value = "szukaj" name = "search"/>
    </p>
    <div id = "searchButton"><a href = "#"      onclick="popUp('paragraph')">Szukaj</a></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is `#menu` define i can't find in your `html`?

Comment: please create a fiddle for what you actually want. I can't see your element in html viewer

Answer (score 0):

Typo!: `searcButton` vs `searchButton`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CNjcP/2/